# How to add scroll on highcharts multiple drilldown

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, visualization

[image]

Im using highcharts that now we have so much item, i need something to make it readable and scrollable, i have added zoom property but it doesnt meet requiriments, any idea?

this is my code :

```
Highcharts.theme = {
    colors: ["#7cb5ec", "#f7a35c", "#90ee7e", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee", "#ff0066", "#eeaaee", "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee"],
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        backgroundColor: null,
        style: {
            fontFamily: "Dosis, sans-serif"
        }
    },
    title: {
        style: {
            fontSize: '16px',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textTransform: 'uppercase'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(219,219,216,0.8)',
        shadow: false
    },
    legend: {
        itemStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '13px'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        title: {
            style: {
                textTransform: 'uppercase'
            }
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px'
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        candlestick: {
            lineColor: '#404048'
        }
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    // General
    background2: '#F0F0EA'
};
```

i have been added zoomType: 'x' for now, but i need to work with scrollable too. what property i should use? i already try highstock but it doesnt work with drilldown charts.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `scrollablePlotArea` property. Also, drilldown works with Highstock: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9ap2sj7k/

```
chart: {
    scrollablePlotArea: {
        minWidth: 1200
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b0f2dq3g/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea